# sorting slice of integer inside a slices

Tags: go, slice

I'm trying to sort slice of int inside a slice, for example :

```
slices := make([][]int32, 0)
slices = append(slices, []int32{10,22})
slices = append(slices, []int32{13,22})
slices = append(slices, []int32{12,22})
// [[10 22] [13 22] [12 22]]
// to become 
// [[10 22] [12 22] [13 22]] (ascending)
// *by the first element in slice
```

i had no idea for that, but i was thinking about append and prepend after check

Comment: Do you want to `insert` in sorted Order? Or are you given a slice of slices to begin with? And do you wnat to sort based on 1st element?

Comment: the second option sir, but the first one is great too, i need to know

Comment: And sort on 1st element of each slice?

Comment: @SauravPrakash yes sir, based on first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is use Slice from sort package

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)
func main() {
    a := [][]int{[]int{10,3}, []int{5,12}, []int{5, 3}, []int{1,1}}
    fmt.Printf("before: %v\n", a)
    sort.Slice(a, func(i,j int) bool{ return a[i][0] < a[j][0]})
    fmt.Printf("after: %v\n", a)
}
```

For stable sort use, sort.SliceStable instead.